# Preventing blue path rectangle in react-simple-maps

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, d3.js

So I'm using react-simple-maps to make a world map, but the default behavior when I click the map is a blue rectangle around that country. I tried to use `preventDefault()` on an `onClick`, but that didn't work to get rid of it. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Here's my code. Thanks for the help!

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import {
  ComposableMap,
  ZoomableGlobe,
  Geographies,
  Geography
} from "react-simple-maps"
import { Motion, spring } from "react-motion"

const mapStyles = {
  width: "90%",
  height: "auto"
}

class Map extends Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick(geography, evt) {
    evt.preventDefault()
}
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
    <Motion
      defaultStyle={{
        x: this.props.center[0],
        y: this.props.center[1]
      }}
      style={{
        x: spring(this.props.center[0]),
        y: spring(this.props.center[1])
      }}
    >
      {({ x, y }) => (
        <ComposableMap
          width={500}
          height={500}
          projection="orthographic"
          projectionConfig={{ scale: 120 }}
          style={mapStyles}
        >
          <ZoomableGlobe center={[x, y]}>
            <circle
              cx={250}
              cy={250}
              r={120}
              fill="transparent"
              stroke="#CFD8DC"
            />

            <Geographies
              disableOptimization
              geography="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/GordyD/49654901b07cb764c34f/raw/27eff6687f677c984a11f25977adaa4b9332a2a9/countries-and-states.json"
            >
              {(geos, proj) =>
                geos.map((geo, i) => (
                  <Geography
                    key={geo.id + i}
                    geography={geo}
                    projection={proj}
                    style={{
                      default: { fill: "#CFD8DC" }
                    }}
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                  />
                ))
              }
            </Geographies>
          </ZoomableGlobe>
        </ComposableMap>
      )}
    </Motion>
  </div>
      )
  }
}
```

[image: export default Map]

Answer (score 7):

Setting the following style on a `Geography` component removes the bounding rectangle on all interactions:

```
style={{
    default: {
        outline: 'none'
    },
    hover: {
        outline: 'none'
    },
    pressed: {
        outline: 'none'
    }
}}
```

Comment: ohhhh...we actually need to set outline to 'none' for each of these (even though the rectangle was only showing on mouse press).  that works!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a CSS rule to the elements that you are clicking:

```
outline: none;
```

Note that this outline is not always a bad thing because it helps with keyboard navigation